# JAXB - detect CDATA element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata

I'm using Java JAXB annotations to process and unmarshall XML document. If content of document is CDATA, it is propertly deserialized to String.

So if element is:

```
<elem><![CDATA[ something ]]></elem>
```

result of this operation

```
@XmlValue
protected String value;
```

is string:

```
\t\n\rsomething\t\n\r
```

which is OK.

Now my problem - how to tell if this element had CDATA annotation, or no - how to differentiate between

```
<elem><![CDATA[ something ]]></elem> 
<elem>something</elem>
```

elements? I tried custom XmlTypeAdapters but no luck (string is already processed when reaches this point).

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193944/jaxb-marshalling-unmarshalling-with-cdata

Comment: I did but it doesn't help with my problem. I have more specific problem than that one. Like I said in my question - I tried custom XmlTypeAdapters but no luck (string is already processed when reaches this point).